# How to save word documents with package officer

Tags: r

I would like to save several word documents according to the regions included in the `region_action_selected` object. Here is the script:

```
fileout <- tempfile(fileext = ".docx",paste(region_actions_select,"_rapport_2018_",format(Sys.time(), "%d%m%y_%H%M%S"),sep=""))


setwd("C:/Users/Documents")
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Can you explain your question more?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a dataframe which has the region names like this:

```
region_action_selected <- data.frame(region = c("USA, Europe, China, Asia"))
```

And according to what I understand that you want to write different files you can use something like this:

```
for(p in 1:nrow(region_action_selected)){

  filenamenum = paste0("C:/Users/Desktop",region_action_selected$region[p],".docx")

  tempfile(file=filenamenum)
}
```

Please if you can update your question with an example input and expected output I could help more.